# Does EC2 Memory include Memory for OS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Do EC2  instances include the OS memory? 
For example a t3.micro is 1 GB memory but a Windows Server OS will use 2GB just sitting there. 
The AWS website will let you have t3.micro using Windows server but there would seem to be no point, unless the memory they are charging for doesn't include the memory for the  OS itself.
However, I've been unable to find any documentation to tell me either way.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/sys-reqs-19, minimum required RAM is 512MB

Comment: And a t3.nano is 0.5 GB. So that wouldn't be much use if it doesn't exclude  the OS mem.

Comment: It doesn't exclude the OS mem. The OS is usable with 0.5GB, maybe there is "no much use" but some people need only "little use" and AWS offers them to pay only for "little use". If one needs "more use", there are many other instance types.

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon EC2 instance is a normal virtual machine.

All the stated resources (CPU, Memory) will be assigned to the VM for use by the operating system and applications running on the operating system.